# Converting a Win32.exe to DLL

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, dll

I 'm working on a Visual C++ Win32 Project (Visual Studio 2012), consisting of:

-`source.cpp` (Source Files)

-`dialog, icon, accelarator` (Resource Files)

-`resource.h` (Header Files)

I want to convert Win32.exe to Win32.dll, in order to call it from a Windows Forms application. Which is the best way doing this? Do I have to use the source code and put it into a new DLL project or I can just convert it?

I 'm a newbie, and analytical steps would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Create a DLL project. Add your source files. Export functions. Might be easier to put it in a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly.

Comment: Could you please give me some more details? I did create an empty dll project and I added all files. Build was succesful (a .dll file was created), however it says: Unable to start program '....dll'. There is no `DllMain` function in my program. Do I have to add it in source.cpp?

Comment: The win32 template dll proj in vs has a dllmain. How did you export functions.

Comment: I didn't export yet any function. I 'm trying to achieve a succesful DLL convertion. My .cpp contains `WinMain()` among other functions. Where do I have to embed `DllMain`? Thank's in advance.

Comment: You don't want a WinMain. As I said, the default DLL template has your DllMain.

Comment: You cannot *start* a DLL. A DLL is useful only for `LoadLibrary`-calls, either explicit or implicit. What did you expect to happen when you selected *Start Debugging*?

Comment: @IInspectable: You 're right. Thank's.